# Unsupported MacBook for iOS 17 Development

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a mid-2014 MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur. My Xcode is 13.2.1. The latest version of Xcode is no longer supported on my machine, but I've been able to download the latest Device Support files from GitHub and manually place them in the Xcode directory to continue working without issues. So I can continue develop to iOS 16. So far everything has been good. The latest iOS 16 is working good too.
However, I can't seem to find Device Support files for iOS 17 on GitHub, and I've heard that this method won't work anymore. Is this true?

Is there any other way I can continue using my MacBook Pro for development to iOS 17?  I came across something called "OpenCore Legacy Patcher" – if I install that, will it allow me to download the latest version of Xcode and work with it?
Or any other way?
Or will I need to purchase a new MacBook?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: OCLP is entirely 'at your own risk'. Before trying it, get a known-good Time Machine backup or for belt & braces, also a clone. Then you can test in safety.